# how to download audio file from from uri and save in local folder in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I've got various types of ringtone in my server. I need to know how to read those audio files and save into my Windows Phone 8 directory.

Comment: There are vaious answers about 'how to download a file in WP8'. Can you show what you have tried and where you have encountered problems? You should also be aware about [supported media in WP8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: do you want to do this in code or by hand?

Comment: StreamResourceInfo streamResourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65265347/dog38catsi_a2yn44rm.mp3", UriKind.Absolute)); THIS LINE OF CODE GENERATE EXCEPTION "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code"

Answer (score -1):

How large are the files? The BackgroundTransferRequest API is one way you could download files. It is especially useful for larger files. Since this class downloads in the background it is nice in that you can navigate around your app and even leave it without having to cancel your download.

It also has some built-in functionality that will help limit downloads when you are on wireless vs wifi so your app won't accidentally eat up your user's data plan.

Here's some info on Background file transfers:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202955%28v=vs.105%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202959%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

An alternative is using an Http request using either the HttpWebRequest or WebClient classes. These options are good when you have smaller files and when you know you have a stable network connection. They will also work with larger files but they don't have the extra features that BackgroundTransfer API has for longer running downloads.

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Making_a_HTTP_request_and_listening_its_completion_in_Windows_Phone

Comment: StreamResourceInfo streamResourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65265347/dog38catsi_a2yn44rm.mp3", UriKind.Absolute)); THIS LINE OF CODE GENERATE EXCEPTION "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code"